# Angular returns empty object when try to pupulate it (object contains private properties)

Tags: angular, properties, private

I have a class with private properties which looks like:

```
    export class newItem{
  private _id: number;
  private _description: string;
  private _insertDate: any;
  private _updateDate: any;
  private _value: number;

  get id() : number {
    return this._id;
  }
  set id(name : number) {
    this._id = name;
  }
  get description() : string {
    return this._description;
  }
  set description(description : string) {
    this._description = description;
  }
  get insertDate() : string {
    return this._insertDate;
  }
  set insertDate(insertDate : string) {
    this._insertDate = insertDate;
  }
  get updateDate() : string {
    return this._updateDate;
  }
  set updateDate(updateDate : string) {
    this._updateDate = updateDate;
  }
  get value() : number {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(value : number) {
    this._value = value;
  }

}
```

I use this class when I want to add new `item`. Then my `.html` file looks like:

```
 <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.description"></td>
      <td><input type="date" disabled [(ngModel)]="newItem.insertDate"></td>
      <td><input type="date" disabled [(ngModel)]="newItem.updateDate"></td>
      <td><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="newItem.value"></td>
      <td>
        <i
          class="fa fa-plus-square add-button"
          (click)="addItem(newItem)">
        </i>
      </td>
```

But when I print what is inside the `newItem` in `addItem()` method:

```
addItem(newItem){
    console.log('new item', newItem);
}
```

and when you go to the browser you will notice that the object `newItem` is empty:
[image]

Can you tell me why this object is empty and how can I populate it to save properly the object in `database`?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular 4 if it is what you are asking about

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code within your class and component?

Comment: Maybe you need to create object (not class) ?

Comment: I have updated a question in which I put the whole class of `newItem` with setters and getters